# Plot the solution of an equation

Tags: plotting

```
{a, b} = {6, 7};
t = 0;
dt = 0.001;
Do[{l, m} = With[{r = NSolve[{x - y == a, 2 x + y == b}, {x, y}]},
    Extract[r, Position[r, _?NumericQ]]];
    t = t + dt;
    a = a + (l + m)a dt;
    b = b + l m b dt, {1000}]
```

How to plot `a(b)`, `a(t)` ?

Comment: You don't have functions `a[t]`, `b[t]` produced by your code, just two individual numbers, `a` and `b` with values `2.45035` and `0.0609429`, respectively.

Answer (score 7):

Adam, I think this is probably what you mean:

```
{a, b} = {6, 7};
t = 0;
dt = 0.001;

loopvals = Part[#, 2, 1] &@
   Reap@
    Do[
     {l, m} = 
      With[{r = NSolve[{x - y == a, 2 x + y == b}, {x, y}]}, 
       Extract[r, Position[r, _?NumericQ]]];
     t = t + dt;
     a = a + (l + m) a dt;
     b = b + l m b dt;
     Sow[{a, b}],
     {1000}
    ];

results = Transpose@Prepend[loopvals, {6, 7}];
ListLinePlot[results, PlotLegends -> {"a", "b"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Do` loops return `Null`, so you have to actively save your values as they are calculated. `Sow` and `Reap` are one of the most efficient ways to do so, as you can see in this [excellent tutorial from WRI](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/) on writing fast *Mathematica* code, and in countless posts on this site.

---

Your code has other problems as well.

1. The system of equations you solve numerically at each iteration admits a simple analytical solution. You should really solve that symbolically once and then use the solution repeatedly.

For instance, if you solve the linear system, you obtain the following expressions for your recursion:

```
Clear[a, b, l, m]
{l, m} = {x, y} /. First@Solve[{x - y == a, 2 x + y == b}, {x, y}];
FullSimplify[{a + (l + m) a dt, b + l m b dt}]

(* Out: 
{a - 1/3 a (a - 2 b) dt, b + 1/9 b (-2 a + b) (a + b) dt}
*)
```

2. Loops are typically a bad idea in Mathematica and they can be almost always avoided. You will want to look into alternative constructs. Read through this Q&A on this site: [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica).

Combining both points, you can use the explicit recursion rule derived above and the idiomatic [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) command to apply this recursion rule repeatedly:

```
results = Transpose@
    NestList[
      Function[list,
        With[{a = list[[1]], b = list[[2]], dt = 0.001}, 
          {a - 1/3 a (a - 2 b) dt, b + 1/9 b (-2 a + b) (a + b) dt}]
      ],
      {6, 7},
      10000
    ];
```

Your original approach with `NSolve` took 8.34s to calculate 10,000 iterations; an approach still using `Do`, but using the pre-calculated solution (code not shown) takes 0.059s, yielding a 140x speedup; the idiomatic `NestList` approach above takes 0.002s to do the same, i.e. it is more than 4000x faster than the original, and 30x faster than `Do`.

---

Having said that, I do have one further comment: you need to learn to write better questions! Your question was barely intelligible, you had no code formatting, and you showed no effort to solve your problem yourself, and this is not the first question you asked on this site!

Comment: you are strict but just. someday, i'll ask a question which is as good as your answer, thank you.

Comment: ...and if one wants to avoid component extractions: `With[{dt = 0.001}, Transpose @ NestList[Function[list, list (1 + dt Total[list] {{-1/3, 2/3}, {-2/9, 1/9}}.list)], {6, 7}, 10]]`

Answer (score 3):

Just another way to do this:

```
m = {{1, -1}, {2, 1}};
fun = {{1 + (#1 + #2) 0.001, 0}, {0, 1 + #1 #2 0.001}} &;
nf[x_] := fun @@ (Inverse[m].x).x
```

So,

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[NestList[nf, {6, 7}, 1000]],, PlotLegends -> {"a", "b"}]
```

yielding:

[image]

*** Verbatim instructive comment from @Guesswhoitis.***

It's alright here, but in general, it's better to use `LinearSolve[]` instead of `Inverse[]`:

```
lsf = LinearSolve[{{1, -1}, {2, 1}}];
nf[x_] := fun @@ x.lsf[x].
```

Comment: It's alright here, but in general, it's better to use `LinearSolve[]` instead of `Inverse[]`: `lsf = LinearSolve[{{1, -1}, {2, 1}}]; nf[x_] := fun @@ x.lsf[x]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. thank you just wanted to point out a `Nest` approach but will add to answer:)